# is there any way to use @Async for a method being called N amount of times but know when it processed all calls?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

Ive been trying to find out if this is possible (working with spring).

What I basically want to do is this:

I have a process, that has to make a huuuge comparation between many records and the records of the database, so, because I want to avoid a timeout exception I was thinking about use my method and call an async. method that will actually take each comparation and go to the database to see if it exists or not.

It works great, but , what I dont know , how to know from my first method (where I call the aysnc method) if all the calls at this method are finished.

Is there any way to do this?

My async method looks like this:

```
@Async 
Future<String> myMethod(someParams){
    someCode...
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve that is to get a hold of the `ExecutorService` used by that `@Async` method under the hoods. You can, for instance, pass your own executor service as `@Async("customExecutorServiceBeanName")`.

Once you have that, you can simply call [shutdown()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()) and then [awaitTermination()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) on that executor service instance (probably from within some `@PreDestroy` method).

Comment: thanks! excuse me, dont you have some code example of this?

Comment: Have a look at the **Usage Examples** in the `ExecutorService` javadoc; the `shutdownAndAwaitTermination()` sample method seems to cover this quite well: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html